# Fruit identification - Fruit bought in China

Tags: fruit, food-identification

Does anyone know what this fruit is? I bought some from a lady in Yangshuo, China. It’s sweet and crunchy. Tastes a bit like an apricot mixed with a peach... Fruit and seed shown in picture.

I have asked locals who say it is a type of plum, and another who said it was maybe a hybrid plum-apricot. I was thinking it might be a loquat but the seed is too small.

[image]

Comment: For a Pluot ( hybrid from plum and abricot) the seed seems different : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluot

Comment: Thanks. Yes I came across a pluot, but the stone is mich smaller and also it doesn’t have a different coloured darker skin like a pluot does. The flesh of this fruit and the outer ‘skin’ just blend together.

Comment: What sort of texture is the seed? If you still have any fruit and the seed, could you post with some scale and other perspectives (e.g. edge towards camera, top towards camera etc. If at all possible photos of the flowers as they are often the key to identification of plants.